# The phrase 'Africa of Blue'

Tags: idioms

I was reading Martin Amis' 'London Fields' and I came across this sentence -

> 'The sky was also empty, blown clean, an Africa of blue'.

I could not understand it. So, can anyone explain to me what it means?

Comment: What's the rest of the context? It says the sky was "**also...**",  so there is another thing here that's important.  Were they perhaps on a clear blue lake?

Comment: The character was in the midst of a bare lot. Hence, the **'also'**.

Comment: And from the bare lot, you have the answer: He's thinking of the bare plains of Africa. The cloudless sky is as clean as a desert or a dry plain.

Comment: @skymninge, I suppose that makes sense, though it still does not make sense why Africa can be equated with something barren. Thanks  for the clarification.

Comment: Because of the Sahara, most likely.

Answer (score 1):

Africa is  the land of nature without inhibitions,one of the best examples of abandon and bounty of the Gods, unsoiled, natural, care free.

The blue of the sky was as uninhibited, unmarred by clouds or any other obstruction.

The sky was also empty, blown clean,..sets a prelude to the pure abandon of blue.Africa here refers only to blue and not the starkness as being speculated in the comments.